# How to insert multiple records in a table through single call

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, user-defined-types

My database table structure is as follow:

tableName: `StructureTable`

```
Field 1: FiledName
Field 2: FieldValue
Field 3: Comments
```

stored procedure is as follow:

```
       3 input param:@FiledName,@FieldValue,@Comments

       BEGIN
              INSERT INTO StructureTable (FiledName,FieldValue,Comments) Values(@FiledName,@FieldValue,@Comments)


       END
```

Now, from front end, i am going to insert 7 fields as follow:

```
FieldName | FieldValue |    Comment 
---------------------------------------
  Name        John        name insert
Profession   Analyst       Profession
```

...

I have created one procedure which has `insert/update` script.

**PROBLEM**: i dont' want to make 7 times call to insert 7 field into database.

I want to make sigle call and make 7 fields entry as above.

Please suggest any approach or share any code to achieve this.

I am using `SQL Server 2008` and `ADO.NET`

Thank You

Comment: I have not written code yet. i want to know the approach. For now, i just think to go with multiple insert call to sql.

Comment: but you said that you made a procedure.

Comment: How about a bulk insert or something like this - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/29/sql-server-three-methods-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-single-table-sql-in-sixty-seconds-024-video/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using both Sql Server 2008 and ADO.Net, the recommended way to accomplish the task of passing a multiple sets of parameters is by using a [Table Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That documentation link also gives an overview of other methods that developers have used in the past, such as comma delimted strings, xml documents, or bulk copy. DataTables are also possible, but not necessary if you are not already using them. TVP's are the technology that Microsoft has provided exactly for this scenario.

Once you get the User-Defined-Table-Type created in your database, and get the ADO.Net code setup to fill an instance of that TVP, you will want to know how to fill it, which is not always obvious. You could use a DataTable, which is what the link that BAdmin provided gives an example of. Unfortunately, he did not explain well that you are not sending a DataTable to the store procedure, but rather you are filling a TVP from a DataTable. You could also use a DataReader (if you were reading the parameter values from another resultset, which you are not) or an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` which is fairly easy to create once you get the hang of it (see [SqlDataRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqldatarecord%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Here is an excellent tutorial on setting up a class that provides an enumerator of SqlDataRecord from a list of objects: http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/